# Css div width problem

Tags: css

i have div with 500px width which contains multiple anchors... problem anchors not wrapping in to multiple lines.... i tried using table as well same problem....

```
<div  style="width:500px;">
    <a href="#procrit">procrit</a>&nbsp;
    <a href="#doxil">doxil</a>&nbsp;
    <a href="#prezista">prezista</a>&nbsp;
    <a href="#simponi">simponi</a>&nbsp;
    <a href="#reopro">reopro</a>&nbsp;
    <a href="#topamax">topamax</a>&nbsp;
    <a href="#invega">invega</a>&nbsp;
    <a href="#axert">axert</a>&nbsp;
    <a href="#aciphex">aciphex</a>&nbsp;
    <a href="#concerta">concerta</a>&nbsp;
    <a href="#risperdal">risperdal</a>&nbsp;
    <a href="#remicade">remicade</a>&nbsp;
    <a href="#velcade">velcade</a>&nbsp;
    <a href="#doxil">doxil</a>&nbsp;
    <a href="#regranex">regranex</a>&nbsp;
    <a href="#nucynta">nucynta</a>&nbsp;
    <a href="#duragesic">duragesic</a>&nbsp;
    <a href="#leustatin">leustatin</a>&nbsp;
    <a href="#invega">invega</a>&nbsp;
    <a href="#sustenna">sustenna</a>&nbsp;
    <a href="#reminyl">reminyl</a>&nbsp;
    <a href="#natrecor">natrecor</a>&nbsp;
</div>
```

Comment: You need to format your HTML as code by indenting it with four spaces.  You will then be able to use `<a>` tags.  Also, please add newlines.

Comment: i don't want every anchor in new line... after exceeding specified width it must come in the next row...

Comment: You should add newlines to your code so that people can read it.

Comment: edited for readability - acknowledged that it should be single line for purposes stated

Answer (score 6):

Try replacing `&nbsp;` with just a space character. `&nbsp;` prevents the browser from wrapping words it is attached to. Each `<a>` will not appear on a new line, but it will successfully wrap if it no longer fits its container if using normal spaces.

Answer (score 1):

If there is no white-space between the anchors, it is considered all one string and therefore can not wrap. You could try to use the CSS rule `word-wrap` to help with this, but some browsers may not honor such a setting.

Simple solution is to change `&nbsp;` to an actual spaces. Or use a `<ul>` and have the `<li>` `display: inline;`. The latter is arguably more semantic.

Comment: that's the reason i added &nbsp;

Comment: `&nbsp;` is a *non-breaking space* and therefore still doesn't break.

Answer (score 0):

Use `float:left;margin-right:5px`

`&nbsp;` is a naughty way to force spacing; you'll get much more consistent and professional results with good CSS (in this case, `margin`).